# defining default values in makefile

Tags: command-line, makefile

My makefile has line like this

```
   CFLAGS = -c -g -D OPT1 -D OPT2
```

I want to pass this arguments through command line like this

```
 make ARG1= OPT1 ARG2 =OPT2
```

If I dont pass these arguments through command line I want makefile to use  take default values  defined in makefile. How do I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing additional variables from command line to make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just do something like this in the makefile:

```
OPT1 = MY_OPT_1 # defaults
OPT2 = MY_OPT_2

CFLAGS = -c -g -D $(OPT1) -D $(OPT2)
```

Then on the command line:

```
$ make -e OPT1=SOME_OTHER_OPT1 OPT2=SOME_OTHER_OPT2
```

When you specify falues for `OPT1` and/or `OPT2` on the command line these will override the default values in the makefile.

Note that you probably want the `-e` option with `make` in most cases to force everything to be re-built with the new `OPT1`, `OPT2` values.

Comment: Use
#ifdef OPT2
#endif
in your c/cpp file

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use the `?=` assignment operator. It only assigns the value if it is not defined at runtime.

```
OPT1?=opt1_default
OPT2?=opt2_default
```

and at call-time you just

```bash
make OPT1=a OPT2=b
# OR
make # to use default values
```

[more info](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html)

Comment: `?=` lets you override with an env variable or a flag, while `=` (and `:=`) only accepts a flag.