# Linux kernel Make predefined macros

Tags: linux, build, kernel

What are the list of predefined Make macros available for linux kernel build

I have come across

> make V=0|1 [targets] 0 => quiet build (default), 1 => verbose build
>
> make V=2 [targets] 2 => give reason for rebuild of target
>
> make O=dir [targets] Locate all output files in "dir", including
>   .config
>
> make C=1 [targets] Check all c source with $CHECK (sparse by default)
>
> make C=2 [targets] Force check of all c source with $CHECK

Then soon I have come across a macro M

$ make M=drivers/usb/serial

which will build all the needed files in that directory and link the final module images.

I am wondering where can I find the complete list of all make macros.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not macros, just variable assignment. Then makefile decides what to do depending on that variables. Take a look on
[Passing additional variables from command line to make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make)