# Make global options

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile

I  have some project with alot of files and i want to compile them all with `-Wall`,
 how can I do it on linux, without changing `makefile`.

```
make -Wall
```

doesn't help.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how the makefile is written - there is not necessarily a way to do this - definitely not a general way for all cases. Give th emakefile and we might be able to help but it would be better if you could learn the makefile syntax an suggest ways that we can correct when it does not work.

Comment: This question might help for editing the makefile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to do something like

```
make CC='gcc -Wall' CXX='g++ -Wall'
```

which will tell make to use 'gcc -Wall' as the C compiler and `g++ -Wall` as the C++ compiler

This assumes all the sources are C and C++ and that the makefile uses the `CC` and `CXX` variables, and that it uses GCC as the compiler, and probably several other assumptions.

Typically compilation flags are stored in make variables such as `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` but if you override them you might replace existing options that are necessary for correct operation, so adding options to `CC` and/or `CXX` is sometimes safer.

Comment: Can i anyhow do not change options, i mean only add?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. There is no way to add to existing variables on the command line, you can only override them. To add to the options you must edit the makefile