# GNU make nested rules

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

I want to achieve the following syntax using a makefile:

```
make install program1
make install program2
```

Right now i have a simple makefile:

```
install:
    #installing program1...
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve the syntax i want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing additional variables from command line to make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. What's the "nesting"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Maybe nested isn't a good description. It comes from my logic of the command is: i'm looking for an installation in the make file, which is for program1. I was expecting that nested logic to be somehow applied to the makefile. something like: 

install:
    program1: ..
    program2: ..

Comment: @TimF answers you question. You don't like that answer, but you can't
have the answer you consider more elegant. The `make` commandline
syntax is: `make [FLAGS] [(VAR=VALUE|TARGET)...]`. So
`make install program1` means: make targets `install` and `program1`.
and `make install PROGRAM=progam1` means: make target install with
`$(PROGRAM)` = `program1`. Nothing you can do in a makefile can change that.  You'd have to change `make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a variable called PROGRAM=... in your Makefile and your target install would look like :

```
install:
#installing $(PROGRAM)
```

Then you could call make like this :

```
make install PROGRAM=program1
```

Comment: I know, but i think it is less elegant than:

    make install program1

Comment: @amitlevin It might be less elegant, but other solutions (like looking inside the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`) inside the Makefile have much much less elegant implementation.

Comment: If "install" is the default target, you can get a little closer to the behavior your looking for by using the variable name "install" instead of "PROGRAM", allowing you to type "make install=program1"