# C/C++ Cyanogenmod How to compile kernel using different version of toolchain?

Tags: c++, c, kernel, cyanogenmod, linux-toolchain

I am trying to compile kernel for Cyanogenmod 13. I am getting error

```
ERROR: modpost: Found 2 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
 To build the kernel despite the mismatches, build with:
'make CONFIG_NO_ERROR_ON_MISMATCH=y'
 (NOTE: This is not recommended)
```

I read it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/solved-stock-kernel-build-problems-t2532147). That i need to compile my kernel using 4.7.
How can i choose the version of toolchain during cyanogenmod build ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @nopasara and his valuable comment.

So i did little research further and discovered that the kernel is compatiable with `arm-eabi tool chain` not `arm-linux-androideabi` toolchain. So here is the command i used

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/android/system/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-eabi-4.7/bin/ && export ARCH=arm && export SUBARCH=arm && export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-eabi- && make msm8226_defconfig O=~/android/system/out/target/product/E6790/obj/KERNEL_OBJ
```

and

```
 make   O=~/android/system/out/target/product/E6790/obj/KERNEL_OBJ zImage -j4
```

To do with this Cyanogenmod add following line to your BoardConfig.mk

```
  TARGET_KERNEL_CROSS_COMPILE_PREFIX := arm-eabi-
```

and either use

```
 export TARGET_LEGACY_GCC_VERSION=4.7
```

Or edit ~/android/system/build/core/combo/TARGET_linux-arm.mk and set version in

```
  $(combo_2nd_arch_prefix)TARGET_LEGACY_GCC_VERSION := 4.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to setup gcc version 4.7 and use CC variable to set it as a compiler. E.g. `make target CC=/bin/gcc4.7`

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).

Comment: im trying method from this post, thanks for ur reply. i will try urs too. http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-switching-to-custom-toolchain-t2927662

Comment: just noticed that in your post there is a link to manual describing toolchain setup:     `export PATH=$PATH:<NDK_PATH>/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/
    export ARCH=arm
    export SUBARCH=arm
    export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-
    make hammerhead_defconfig
    make -j2` Here `PATH` environment variable is added by toolchain path. Just make sure that needed toolchain directory is first in PATH directory list.