# Have an argument that should not be hardcoded but should be passed as an argument at the time of rule invocation

Tags: bash, makefile

Have a makefile in which rule `dev-create-empty-migration`, currently, this rule has hardcoded argument `accounts_table`, this argument should not be hardcoded but should be passed as an argument at the time of rule invocation. e. g. make `dev-create-empty-migration accounts_table`.

Any ideas how to do that?

```
.PHONY: dev-create-empty-migration
dev-create-empty-migration:
    migrate create -ext sql -dir
./pkg/acc/repo/postgres/migrations accounts_table
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826178/7301613), it will probably solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use a variable and store something in it. By using `?=`, make first searches for an argument. If found, it uses the argument, otherwise the default content.

```
$ cat Makefile 
VAR     ?= derp
test:
        @echo $(VAR)
$ make
derp
$ make VAR=lala
lala
```

Just because it's fun, you can also do something as follows. This omits the use of additional arguments, but you could of course make some hybrid.

```
$ cat Makefile 
VAR     := None

dev-create-empty-migration-%_table:
        $(eval VAR=$(patsubst dev-create-empty-migration-%,%,$@))
        @echo $(VAR)
$ make dev-create-empty-migration-derp_table
derp_table
```