# How to add command-line arguments while running a program using Makefile?

Tags: java, makefile, compilation

I have the following Main class in java where I pass arguments from the command-line:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Conversion c = new Conversion();
        c.convertHPP(args[0], args[1]);
        c.convertCPP(args[0], args[1]);
    }
}
```

I have a Makefile and with the option make `run-java` I run the program:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
          Main.java \
          Conversion.java \
          Book.java

make-java: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run-java:
    java Main
    
clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

What I want to do is to pass the command-line arguments (argv) which are the name of the files to convert, from the makefile to the main. I want to do something like this in the terminal:

```
make java-run arg1 arg2
```

How can I change my Makefile so that the `run-java:` can allow me to pass arguments and to send it to the main?

Thanks !

Comment: This might help. [passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make)

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable:

```
make run-java ARGS="arg1 arg2"
```

And then in the makefile:

```
run-java
    java Main $(ARGS)
```