# How to control behavior of makefile by a macro definition in a header?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

In my project, I define a macro called `ACT_STATE` in a header file `config.h` to make different blocks of code be compiled. Macro `ACT_STATE` could be `ACT_DEVELOP`(value 0) or `ACT_DEPLOY`(value 1), I want source files in a folder called `User` could be compiled at state `ACT_DEPLOY` and leave those source files alone at state `ACT_DEVELOP`. I know I can pass macro definition to makefile while calling `make`, but by this way I need to define `ACT_STATE` twice. Therefore, I think if it is possible to let `make` read macro definition from head files, so it could compile different files depending on macro definition in a header file?

Comment: There isn't a standard or easy way to have make read a macro value from a header.  It would be more usual to have make specify the value so the header doesn't have to, or so the header specifies a default if make does not specify the value.

Comment: There is no need to define the macro twice. If you pass it through Make (`make ACT_STATE=ACT_DEPLOY`) then there is no reason to define it in the header.

Comment: Remember that C code (in particular some `#include`d file) can be *generated* by a program. The [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) tool  could be useful to you

Comment: @Beta for a proper config management it is desirable to not hinge upon the very transient and volatile command line which starts the build process. Of course one can always add another layer of scripting, but IMHO this isn't desirable either.

Comment: @Vroomfondel: I have seen config management systems that performed, e.g., sweeping backups and builds of the main branch every midnight. But I've never seen a build system that could build something on command in a way that *didn't* hinge on the command line. (I am, of course, not counting GUI-based abominations). If there's a better alternative, I'm keen to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

[Preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html),

```
gcc -D name=definition
```

However, `ACT_DEVELOP 0` and `ACT_DEPLOY 1` is not the simplest way to make a binary variable. There is no reason why one can't write `#define ACT_STATE 7` or `#undef ACT_STATE`, leading to complicated range checks. A preferable way is `#ifdef` or `#if defined(...)`.

```
gcc -D name
```

Unless you have a good reason to do this, consider the `C` standard [assert.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/assert.h.html). With `C11`, one can do `static_assert` that is really useful in some cases. The `assert.h` trigger is `NDEBUG`, which, when defined, makes `assert` arguments compile to `(void)0`.

Also see [passing additional variables to `make`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make) to edit one's `Makefile`.