# Why does ```CFLAGS:=$(CFLAGS) -O3``` not work as expected?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Makefile like this**:

```
CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O3

test: main.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
        rm test *.o -f
```

**compile 1**: command: `make`, output: `gcc  -O3 -o test main.c`

**compile 2**: command: `make CFLAGS="-Wall -Werror"`, output: `gcc -Wall -Werror -o test main.c`

**question**: why not output: `gcc -Wall -Werror -O3 -o test main.c` ?

Comment: I see this writing in minizip: https://github.com/madler/zlib/commit/2014a993addbc8f1b9785d97f55fd189792c2f78

Comment: Is it my usage wrong?

Comment: maybe you need [`override`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive) here, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826178/3985859

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks!   'override' make it work.

Answer (score 0):

use **override** directive:

```
override CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O3
```

or

```
override CFLAGS += -O3
```