# Taking Input with Makefiles

Tags: git, makefile

Basically, I'm trying to automate the pushing process of code to github with makefiles, but I want me to be able to provide the commit message to the Makefile before it commits, this is why I want to have inputs in my Makefile.

I haven't tried anything yet as I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a possible duplicate of [Passing additional variables from command line to make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make).

As the second option presented in the question above suggests, you could set and use a variable `COMMITMSG` inside the Makefile and assign it on the command line: `make COMMITMSG="This is my commit message"`. Didn't test this yet but try it out.