Make executes default rule when I run one target
I have the following file structure:
Filestructure
I have a file called thesis-proposal.tex in the same directory as another directory called "chapters" in which my separate chapter files are in (e.g. introduction.tex and so on). In thesis-proposal.tex I include all of my chapters. Now I want a Makefile, with which I can either compile the whole proposal or a single chapter. I compile a single chapter by creating a temp-wrapper.tex file in which I write the necessary LaTeX lines for compilation.
The Makefile looks as follows:
# Variables
MAIN = thesis-proposal.tex
CHAPTER_DIR = chapters
OUTPUT_DIR = output
CHAPTER_OUT_DIR = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(CHAPTER_DIR)
CHAPTERS = $(wildcard $(CHAPTER_DIR)/*.tex)
LATEXMK = latexmk
TEMP_WRAPPER = temp_wrapper.tex

# Default target: build the full proposal
all: proposal

# Target to build the full proposal
proposal: $(MAIN) $(CHAPTERS)
    mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR)
    $(LATEXMK) -pdf -output-directory=$(OUTPUT_DIR) -interaction=nonstopmode $(MAIN)
    $(LATEXMK) -pdf -output-directory=$(OUTPUT_DIR) -interaction=nonstopmode $(MAIN) # Run twice for references

# This is the rule you run to compile a specific chapter, using "make chapter=<chapter-name>"
chapter: $(CHAPTER_OUT_DIR)/$(chapter).pdf

# Rule to compile a specific chapter (using pattern matching)
$(CHAPTER_OUT_DIR)/%.pdf: $(CHAPTER_DIR)/$*.tex
    mkdir -p $(CHAPTER_OUT_DIR); \
    echo "\documentclass{article}" > $(TEMP_WRAPPER); \
    echo "\\\\begin{document}" >> $(TEMP_WRAPPER); \
    cat $(CHAPTER_DIR)/$*.tex >> $(TEMP_WRAPPER); \
    echo "\\\\end{document}" >> $(TEMP_WRAPPER); \
    $(LATEXMK) -pdf -jobname=$* -output-directory=$(CHAPTER_OUT_DIR) -interaction=nonstopmode $(TEMP_WRAPPER); \
    rm $(TEMP_WRAPPER)

# Clean up
clean:
    rm -rf $(OUTPUT_DIR)

.PHONY: all proposal chapter clean

Why is the proposal rule always triggered when I run make chapter=introduction?
The issue I am having is, when I run make proposal it works as expected, but when I run make chapter=introduction it still runs make proposal. The funny thing is when I comment out the proposal rule I can use the chapter rule and get the expected behavior. I've tried to find out, why this behavior happens, but I failed.

make builds the first target (and all prerequisites of that target, and their prerequisites, etc.) in the makefile by default, unless you tell it to build something else.  When you run make chapter=introduction you have set the chapter variable, but you haven't given a target to build so make still builds the first target (in your makefile, that's all).  If you want make to build the target chapter, you have to say make chapter.  Don't confuse the variable chapter with the target chapter.  They are completely different things.

You did not specify a target, that's why all is running.
Try: make chapter=output chapter to run the script for chapter with the correct value for the variable chapter.
more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826068/724039


Why is the proposal rule always triggered when I run make chapter=introduction?

Why do you think the proposal rule shouldn't run, or that the chapter rule should?
In the command make proposal, the argument proposal is interpreted as a target to build, a so-called goal target.  You may specify any number of goal targets on the command line, including zero.
In the command make chapter=introduction, the argument chapter=introduction is interpreted as a macro assignment. No goal target is explicitly specified.  When no goal targets are specified on the command line, make chooses the first target of the first ordinary rule in the makefile as a goal target.  In your case, that is all, so with your makefile, this command is equivalent to make chapter=introduction all.  Your all has proposal as a prerequisite (and because it is .PHONY, proposal is unconditionally out of date), so the recipe for proposal runs.  On the other hand, chapter is not in the prerequisite tree for all, so its rule is not even considered.
If you want the rule for chapter to run, then you'll need to ask for it explicitly.  For example,
make chapter chapter=introduction

You might also consider using different names for your macros than you do for your targets.  make does not require you to do so, but it would be less prone to confuse you.
