How to pass a variable's value from command line to Makefile
I want to pass a value of a variable from command line to makefile target
In Makefile I have this target
execute -config configuration.json -mode $(mode)

On the command line I want to have
make execute -- -mode stress

How do I update the Makefile target to be able to use the written command on the line?

This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make

This question is similar to: Passing additional variables from command line to make. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jmcarter9t seems you found a duplicate question, well done. In the future, please flag or vote to close as duplicate. Thank you.

You can't do it like this.  Make is not a general-purpose scripting language and makefiles don't have access to the raw command line arguments that make was invoked with.
You have to use a variable assignment, something like this:
make execute MODE=stress

then in your makefile you can write:
MODE = default

mytarget:
         execute -config configuration.json -mode $(MODE)

BTW, the command you wrote is not a "target".  A target is the file that make will create (in my example, mytarget).  The command you wrote is a recipe to build that target.
